# I am getting ads that pop up in front of my activities

Tags: ads

I get some ads that keep popping up. I got fed up of it and clicked the opt-out button next to it. That opened a tab on Chrome, and thats this:

[image]

Can anyone help me disable these ads? I don't know why these ads came in the first place.

Comment: @Izzy those questions do not help me. My phone isn't a Samsung, its a Lenovo K6 Power. I do not have the Premium Wallpapers installed either.

Comment: The phone doesn't matter. Have you noticed it's exactly the same screen shown there, and its exactly the same URL? Moreover, the answer given by Matthew isn't device specific either.